# Dojo equivalent of $(document).scrollTop?

Tags: jquery, dojo, scrolltop

As you know in jQuery `$(document).scrollTop()` is for checking the scroll position of the window. Can the same function be used in dojo? I used

```
dojo.query('html')[0].scrollTop()
```

But in webkit there is bug - it always returns `0`

Comment: What happens if you query `body` instead of `html` ?

Comment: in Webkit it is ok, but in Firefox sctollTop is 0

Comment: Try creating a `div` that contains everything inside `body` with its width and height set to 100%, see if `scrollTop` on that div behaves as expected.

Answer (score 0):

With `dojo` you have to do:

```
dojo.query('body')[0].scrollTop
```

and beware that `scrollTop` is a property not a function, or you will get the error:

```
TypeError: Property 'scrollTop' of object #<HTMLBodyElement> is not a function
```

**UPDATE**

The above code works fine with Dojo 1.8, Chromium 18.0, Rekonq 0.8 and Firefox 17.0 on Ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: This code is wrong in Firefox,  scrollTop allways equal  **0**

Comment: Doesn't `dojo.query('body')[0] === document.body`? Returns true for me, so this is vanilla JS. Anyway, both `dojo.query("body")[0].scrollTop` and `document.body.scrollTop` always give me `0` on Firefox 19 on OSX. `document.documentElement.scrollTop` gives me the correct value in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

If there is still someone interested by this in 2017.
you have to do:

```
dojo.query('body')[0].scrollTop = 0;
```

tested on IE11, Firefox 51.0.1 and Chrome 56.0.xx

Answer (score 0):

Please try `query("html")[0].scrollTop || query("body")[0].scrollTop`.